# Rewriting triple integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm having trouble rewriting a triple integral.

The question is rewrite the following integral in five different ways:

$\int_0^1\int_y^1\int_0^z f(x,y,z) dx dz dy$

I am having trouble with visually seeing the projections onto the different planes because x runs from 0 to z, but z runs from y to 1, so it's hard for me to picture what the bounded regions look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the region of integration is simply $$
\{(x,y,z) : 0\le x\le z, 0\le y\le  z, 0\le z\le 1
\}
$$

Now you can rewrite the integrals in the following ways:
$$
\int_{x}\int_y\int_z\\
\int_{x}\int_z\int_y\\
\int_{y}\int_x\int_z\\
\int_{y}\int_z\int_x\\
\int_{z}\int_y\int_x\\
\int_{z}\int_x\int_y\\
$$

the step is everytime the same:
for the most outer integral, take the smallest possible lower bound and the greatest possible upper bound. Then for the next integral, take the smallest possible lower bound *given the value of the outer variable* and go on.

For example:

the integral given is $$
\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=y}^1\int_{x=0}^z\\
$$

Now if you want to change this to 
$$\int_{x}\int_y\int_z
$$then $x$ varies  between $0$ and $\max z = 1$. So your first integral is 
$$
\int_{x=0}^1
$$

Then you go on until
$$
\int_{x=0}^1 \int_{y=0}^1 \int_{z=\max(x,y)}^1
$$

Comment: Do you mean z = min(x,y)?
I still don't get how you find the max and min given the outer variables

Comment: the max is just the maximum possible value: here, as in the first integral the max for $x$ is $z$ whose upper bound is 1, when $x$ becomes the outer variable its upper bound becomes 1.

Comment: So if I'm following you correctly, the answer in the order dzdydx should be

$\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\int_{z=0}^1$ ??

Comment: no. because for the inner integrals, the bounds depends on the values of the outer variables.

Comment: see my message: "Then for the next integral, take the smallest possible lower bound given the value of the outer variable"